# Replace a two-line string not ending in digit with a one line string

Tags: regular-expressions

I would like to replace a two-line string not ending in digit with a one line string. For example, replacing the following two-line string:

```
Extensions of the Single—Sa1e
Model 414
```

With a one line string:

```
Extensions of the Single—Sa1e Model 414
```

Using `M-x` `replace-regexp`.

My regex pattern to match is `[^[:digit:]]^J`, but I don't know how to capture the non digit part and then refer it in the replace string. How can I do this? Also, how can I specify the new line character?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Type the newline char using `C-q C-j`. Capture parts of the match that you want using regexp groups.  Reuse such group matches using `\N` syntax.

`M-x replace-regexp` `RET` `\([^:digit:]]\)` `C-q C-j` `\(.+\)` `RET` `\1 \2` `RET`

So you enter 3 things, with `RET`: the command name, the regexp, and the replacement. The replacement uses `\N` syntax to reuse groups.

---

If you want to write a command that does this, you write a quick-and-dirty one that just calls what is written above (with backslashes doubled and with `"\n"` in place of `C-q C-j`). But if you want to write a command as it should be written, you would use write a loop that calls `re-search-forward` to find a match and then calls `replace-match` to replace it.  See the Elisp manual, nodes [`Regexp Search`](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Regexp-Search.html#Regexp-Search) and [`Replacing Match`](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Replacing-Match.html#Replacing-Match).

Comment: Thanks. (1) how can I specify that when `M-x replace-regexp`? (2) How can I run your function?

Comment: I edited the answer to make it clear.  You don't want to use `replace-regexp` in Lisp code anyway. Interactively, you don't double the backslashes, and you use `C-q C-j` to insert a newline char in the minibuffer.

Comment: Thanks.  How can I run your original elisp function `foo` on a buffer of text?

Comment: Put point before the text to transform, and use `M-x foo RET`. It was just intended as a short way to show how to use the arguments, but showing it probably confused more than it clarified.

Comment: But do I need to run the definition of `foo` first, so that `M-x foo RET` will work? How to?

Comment: Also if the second line starts with space, will `\(.+\)` match it? It seems not.

Comment: Yes. `.` matches any char except a newline char. If you are going to use regexps with Emacs (and I hope that you do) then you will do yourself a favor by reading the Elisp manual about regexps. It's worth reading it more than once, carefully. And you will come back to it again and again, for details later.

Answer (score 3):

This does not answer your question, since you asked for a regexp to do it, but I think it's worth mentioning that the same can be done easily using a keyboard macro. Start recording with `F3`, search for the regexp with `C-s M-r [^[:digit:]]^J <RET>`, press `Backspace` to join the lines and `F4` to finish the macro. Then repeat by pressing `F4` until all lines are joined.